# PHP MySQL SQL parser (INSERT and UPDATE)

Tags: php, mysql, changelog

I am looking to parse INSERT and UPDATE MySQL SQL queries in PHP to determine what changes where made from what original data. Now this would be pretty easy to create, but I want to see if there are any existing libraries in PHP to do this.

Basically what I have is a table with all of the above queries that have been run on a database. I have already separated out the table name and type of query. I am looking to create a full change log for user viewing based on this data, so I need to get the values of the original INSERT and then changes that are made in each UPDATE. In the end I need field name and new value and with the record id(s). I'll do the rest of the checking/beautifying, including the column name to human readable and if a field value hasn't actually changed.

At the moment, I probably don't need to do multiple table UPDATE's, but it would be useful.

What libraries are there to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://pear.php.net/package/SQL_Parser

http://sourceforge.net/projects/txtsql

http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser

For Perl there's more variety

Comment: The PEAR package is very green and not even v1.0 though.

Comment: Your second link appears to be no longer valid.

Comment: Looks like http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser has been moved to https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser (it's the fastest parser I've tried so far but returns a low-level tree rather than class types like select, insert etc)

Answer (score 3):

A little bit off the question, but maybe a suggestion worth thinking about:

Since MySQL 5.0, the support for triggers is quite good. If you want to keep a record of what changes have been made to a database, instead of storing the sql statements, you could also define insert/update triggers and define another table in which these values can be stored. You could, for example create a simple table having the fields

```
timestamp, user, field, old_value, new_value
```

and insert the respective values whenever a DML on one of your watched tables occured.
To simplify this even more, you could add the field

```
table
```

to the "tracking table" to store all changes to all watched tables in one place.

See the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) for more infos about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

You may give it a chance:
[SQL Parse and Compile](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/5007.html)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook released a open-source PHP version of their [FQL parser](http://developers.facebook.com/opensource.php). From what I was it was quite neat code. You could possibly hack that to work with regular SQL.

Comment: I'm not finding the package you mention. Can you provide a more percise link?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, I found that the PEAR:SQL_Parser package has provided the cleanest short-term solution whilst the PEAR:PHP_Parser_Generator package (the generator that FSQL uses) looks like a really robust longer term solution.

I found txtSQL wasn't robust enough and didn't parse SQL well enough to warrant using, at least in my opinion.

Comment: It appears you've replaced your blog with random pics. The [open bugs](http://pear.php.net/bugs/search.php?cmd=display&package_name[]=SQL_Parser&status=OpenFeedback&bug_type=Bugs) in the PEAR SQL parser have me concerned. Sounds like they've built a generic SQL parser without much special attention for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

you can try :
[dqml2tree sql(dql and dml) query parser written in php](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4916.html)