# mysql split multiquery string with php

Tags: php, mysql, multi-query

I want to make a database restore function that will parse a dump made with phpMyAdmin and will execute all of the queries.

I already have a MySQL class that does the query, but it only knows how to do a single query.  I am looking of a way to split the file content into single queries.

I tried to play with preg_split ... but didn't managed to get it to work.

```
$queries = preg_split('/[(.+);\s*\n/', $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

I am not very good with regular expressions.  Is there a way I can accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to find the right regex:

```
$queries = preg_split('/[.+;][\s]*\n/', $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

it splits the query after the ; sign and does not break even if the query spreads on multiple rows or the query contains ; since it looks for it at the end of a line.

Answer (score 5):

don't try to parse sql with regular expressions. what if there is a `;` somewhere inside a sql string?

i would try http://pear.php.net/package/SQL_Parser, or any of the [other php mysql parsers](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+sql+parser) out there. see also [PHP MySQL SQL parser (INSERT and UPDATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283087/php-mysql-sql-parser-insert-and-update) here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think splitting in comments above will make bad strings when you have stored procedures, functions or triggers in $content.