# Get delimiters from preg_split in PHP

Tags: php, regex

My PHP code:

```
$cmd = 'SELECT var1 FROM var2 GROUP BY var3 LIMIT var4';
// split command
$p = preg_split('/SELECT|FROM|GROUP BY|LIMIT/si', $cmd);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] =>  
  [1] =>  var1 
  [2] =>  var2 
  [3] =>  var3
  [4] =>  var4
)
```

**Is that output below possible?**

```
Array
(
  [SELECT] => var1
  [FROM] => var2
  [GROUP BY] => var3
  [LIMIT] => var4
)
```

Or **is there any way** to get delimiters?

Comment: Have you considered using a SQL parser (you're bound to get wrong results with this regex-hack!)? Checkout: http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/

Comment: @Bart, your comment is IMHO opinion the right answer. You should post it as such.

Comment: @Bart - This example is a little bit different -not too complex like SQL commands. I used it, because it's familiar for everyone.

Comment: @dine: using a parser isn't all that difficult, _and_ is bound to give you less headaches in the long run. Checkout [the examples](http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/), it's really simple.

Comment: @Bart - yeah, i think you right ;) thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cmd = 'SELECT var1 FROM var2 GROUP BY var3 LIMIT var4';

$array = array();
if(preg_match_all('/(SELECT|FROM|GROUP BY|LIMIT)\s+([^\s]+)/si', $cmd, $matches)) {
    $array = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}

var_dump($array);
```

Result:

```
array
  'SELECT' => string 'var1' (length=4)
  'FROM' => string 'var2' (length=4)
  'GROUP BY' => string 'var3' (length=4)
  'LIMIT' => string 'var4' (length=4)
```

Comment: Speed, simple and cute. that's the answer. i just realized. I don't need complex SQL Parser.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a SQL parser? You're bound to get wrong results with this regex-hack.

Checkout:

1. http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser
2. http://pear.php.net/package/SQL_Parser
3. [PHP MySQL SQL parser (INSERT and UPDATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283087/php-mysql-sql-parser-insert-and-update)

A demo with option 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// http://php-sql-parser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/php-sql-parser.php
require_once('php-sql-parser.php');

$cmd = 'SELECT var1 FROM var2 GROUP BY var3 LIMIT var4';
$parser = new PHPSQLParser($cmd);
$parse_tree = $parser->parsed;

echo 'SELECT -> ' . $parse_tree['SELECT'][0]['base_expr'] . "\n";
echo 'FROM   -> ' . $parse_tree['FROM'][0]['table'] . "\n";
echo 'GROUP  -> ' . $parse_tree['GROUP'][0]['base_expr'] . "\n";
echo 'LIMIT  -> ' . $parse_tree['LIMIT']['end'] . "\n";

?>
```

produces:

```
SELECT -> var1
FROM   -> var2
GROUP  -> var3
LIMIT  -> var4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$matches = array();
preg_match ('~^SELECT (?P<SELECT>.+) FROM (?P<FROM>.+) GROUP BY (?P<GROUPBY>.+) LIMIT (?P<LIMIT>.+)~', $cmd, $matches);
```

> Or is there any way to get delimiters?

Regular expressions *always* starts with their delimiters (because its the other way round: The first character *defines* the delimiter)

```
echo $regEx[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

a bit messy...

```
//echo file_get_contents('http://wp.me/pbZy8-1WM');
$cmd = 'SELECT var1 FROM var2 GROUP BY var3 LIMIT var4';
// split command
$pattern = 'SELECT|FROM|GROUP BY|LIMIT';
$p = preg_split('/('.$pattern.')/si', $cmd, null,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
foreach($p as $i => $str)
if (strpos($pattern,$str) !== false)
{
    $rez[$str] = $p[$i+1];
} 
var_dump($rez);
```

gives:

```
  'SELECT' => string ' var1 ' (length=6)
  'FROM' => string ' var2 ' (length=6)
  'GROUP BY' => string ' var3 ' (length=6)
  'LIMIT' => string ' var4' (length=5)
```

Comment: +1 yes a little bit messy, but you too close. your script gives a warning: `Warning: strpos()...`. I didn't get it.

Comment: what is the full text of this warning? never saw it!

Comment: can you try it with this command: `SELECT name, order_id FROM sc_order OF order_products OF product OF users GROUP BY order.order_id LIMIT 1`

Comment: `'SELECT' => string ' name, order_id ' (length=16)
  'FROM' => string ' sc_order OF order_products OF product OF users ' (length=48)
  'GROUP BY' => string ' order.order_id ' (length=16)
  'LIMIT' => string ' 1' (length=2)`  thats it

Comment: yeah, I just put `@` char at the beginning of strpos().

Comment: @dinobeytar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1578/discussion-between-k102-and-dino-beytar)