# Regex Pattern to capture semi-colon delimited database queries

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a script that executes database queries, and I use semi-colons + new line (`\n`) to separate one query from another. See below:

```
CREATE TABLE `moxedo`.`mox_config` (`;`, `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `group_id` INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL , `is_enabled` INT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL , `tag` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `name` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL , `value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `description` TEXT NOT NULL , `init_params` TEXT NOT NULL , `datetime_added` DATETIME NOT NULL , `datetime_lastmodified` DATETIME NOT NULL , `timestamp_univ` BIGINT(14) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) )
ENGINE = INNODB; 
ALTER TABLE `moxedo`.`mox_config` ADD UNIQUE `ix_u_tag_ge` ( `tag` );
```

I'm looking for a Regex Pattern that will help me capture each database query. However, I need to also accommodate the occurrence of semi-colons within the query body, as the code above displays.

I'd appreciate some assistance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex, but a parser, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283087/php-mysql-sql-parser-insert-and-update)

Comment: Using regex for this purpose is nearly as bad as using regex to parse HTML. What if your _data_ contains `;\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
(.*?;)(?!`)(?:\s|$)
```

- `(.*?;)` - match everything followed by a semicolon...
- (?!`) - ... not followed by a single quote
- `(?:\s+|$)` - followed by whitespace characters or the end of the string

If there are other use cases where the semicolon can appear on a different position, the regex will need updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I removed all new line characters from the entire query first though, it just made things easier to deal with. The second grouping doesn't seem to have any effect when I use RegexBuddy and in my code, not sure why.

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh - what do you mean with second grouping? only the first parentheses are capturing - (?!`) is a negative lookahead which only asserts but doesn't consume characters, and (?:\s|$) is a non-capturing group.